# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: c#

I have a C# application where I use remoting. However, some customer recently reported a problem. I get an unusual exception in my code:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

I get an exception when creating a new `TcpChannel`. The code I use is:

```
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider binaryServiceProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
binaryServiceProvider.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider binaryclientProv = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["port"] = portNo;//PortNumber I use is 20052
props["name"] = "ApplicationName";
try
{
    TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(props, binaryclientProv, binaryServiceProvider);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
}
catch (Exception a_Exception)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a_Exception);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(a_Exception);
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/373890/ec2-hosted-asp-net-not-stable